# How to iterate through array 3 at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

How would I be able to iterate through an array and display 3 values in sequential order at a time through a click event?

Example:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
```

Looking for result of:
    `1,2,3` and then click for `4,5,6` then `7,8,9`.

Comment: May you share your code?

Answer (score 4):

Simply increase your loop variable by `3` instead of `1`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
    console.log(array[i], array[i+1], array[i+2]);
    // or console.log(array.slice(i, 3));
}
```

You could also [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/218196) in advance.

---

Edit: Apparently you don't want to iterate (as you say in the title). The same applies to successive clicks though. Keep a counter `i` around and increase it by `3` on each click.

Comment: May be using map we can come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use a counter and show the next three values.

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var counter = 0;
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.append(array[counter++] + array[counter++] + array[counter++]);
});
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, if you don't mind mutating your original array.

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

function clickMeForThree(arr) {
    for (let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i])
        array.shift()
    }
}

clickMeForThree(array)
clickMeForThree(array)
clickMeForThree(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function that returns current value and increments the index counter. Then call it thrice to get next three values.

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var curr = 0;
function nextVal(){
    if(curr<array.length)
        return array[curr++];
    else
        return '';
}

function printNextThree(){
    console.log(nextVal()+','+nextVal()+','+nextVal());
}
```

Now simply call `printNextThree()` function on your click event for the desired result.